Azure AD B2C company branding for the -Change Password- page
How can I specify the custom branding image in Azure AD B2C for the Reset Password page?
I have an Azure AD B2C tenant that is utilizing Company Branding to specify custom images for the various pages such as Login, Sign up etc.  This works as expected except on the 'change password' page.  Another internal group has resolved this somehow but I cannot identify what they did.  We are using Custom Policies. I want to avoid referencing a custom html file, that seems like more trouble than it is worth.
Login page (correct)

Change Password page (incorrect, default logo is displayed)

Edit:
From what I read, it was suggested the selfAsserted version should be updated to resolve this issue.  The other B2C tenant has modified their custom policies to reference selfAsserted version 2.1.7 without an issue.  However when we do so we get an error 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred'.  I can't find any helpful information in the audit or application insight logs.
Content Definition

Technical Profile

Edit: Adding Orchestration Steps
SubJourney PasswordReset

UserJourney CustomSignUpSignIn, OrchestrationStep 3


To specify a custom branding image for the "Change Password" page in Azure AD B2C using Custom Policies, ensure you are updating the OrchestrationStep for the password reset flow and referencing the correct custom branding settings in the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file. Specifically, ensure that the <ContentDefinitions> section for the "Change Password" page includes a reference to the custom branding, similar to the login page configuration.

@Rukmini I have verified I am following your suggestions, however can you clarify what you mean by "includes a reference to the custom branding"?  See my edit, I am showing the TechnicalProfile and ContentDefinitions.  I am getting an error when updating the selfAsserted version reference, which from what I read, is a possible resolution.

I made a few updates to correctly reflect the entire path from UserJourney to the content definition.  @Rukmini.

So did it work?

Sorry my answer was not clear.  No, I just updated the OP for clarity.

The assets used for company branding need to be uploaded to the AzureAD B2C tenant via the Entra Admin Portal GUI. Then, any component that references a branded asset, such as a html template used for a given self asserted page in custom policy, will display the custom branding.

Sign into the Entra Admin Portal https://entra.microsoft.com/
Search for and select "Company Branding" in the top search bar
Select the "Default sign-in" tab, click edit, upload your assets

You will now find that your company branding shows up on B2C self asserted pages.
PSA: due to caching on the servers which serve custom policy, changes to custom policy, assets, etc. can take anywhere from 30 minutes to 1 hour. If you have your custom policy set deployed in dev mode, this time will be cut down to roughly ~ 5 minutes.
The custom policy starter pack Microsoft provides will automatically show this branding without any customizations should you follow the tutorial.
If you are still having issues after uploading your branding to the AzureAD B2C tenant I recommend implementing the starter pack as a separate policy set, observe your branding properly rendered on a self asserted page, then reverse engineer/compare/contrast the starter pack custom policy with your own to fill in the gaps.
As a final reminder, ensure you are actually "in" your AzureAD B2C tenant when uploading your branding assets. For admins who use a single account to hop between multiple tenants... they sometimes (myself included) get mixed up what context they are in. You can change tenants using the tenant switcher here.

Thanks for you answer, but I already have implemented branding, I am just having issues with the Password reset Custom Policy.  All other Custom Polices are working as expected and correctly show the branding images.

@davewilliams459 we are using urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7 for our api.localaccountpasswordreset version. We also have customized the base template. I see you mentioned that any version above 1.1.0 causes issue. Have you tried 2.1.7 specifically? B2C Custom Policy is always a fun time haha.

To resolve I modified the B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE policy selfAsserted to a later version.  However, I also had to add ":contract" in addition to upgrading the version from 1.1.0 to 2.1.7.
Credit to bolt-io  for his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79277857/312826

